# Service stop doing its job after removing app from recent apps list

Tags: android, android-service

I have created an android service that extends from `Service` class, as explained in the example here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html. The Service has a broadcast receiver for the bluetooth state, so I can perform actions when turning on/off bluetooth and create notifications.

It works pretty well even if I go to the home screen and use other apps. But if I remove the application from the recent apps list, I stop getting logs and the notifications are no longer created. However, in the system settings I still can see the service is running.

How can I make the service to keep performing its job even after removing the app from the recent app list?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your process will be terminated when the user swipes your app off the overview screen. When your process restarts (e.g., your services is returning something like `START_STICKY` from `onStartCommand()`), you will need to set up your Bluetooth stuff again.

Comment: There's nothing you can do in order to keep the service  doing its job once you remove the application from "recent apps list" as entire app's process is killed. 

You can rely on START_STICKY which will cause service recreate once device reclaims more memory as @CommonsWare pointed. 

Alternatively, you could set your service (and thus your app) to be resistant towards being killed by the System when you hide the app in backround by invoking setForeground() on the Service (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification)).

Comment: Effectively, after removing the app from recent apps list the service is recreated, calling the onCreate method. On this method I create a new Thread. However, after reccreating the activity, the thread is not created. Why does that happen?